# What does a CREATOR field look like?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

My Parcelable class wants me to include a `CREATOR` field, but I have no idea what such a field looks like. I have silenced the complaint with `SupressLint` in the meanwhile but would like to have that `CREATOR` field. Any idea what it looks like?

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@Parcelize
class RecipeTemplate: Parcelable {
    var recipeHeader: String? = null
    var recipeText: String? = null
    var recipeImage: String? = null
    var recipeKey: String? = null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Joao Alves](https://proandroiddev.com/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize-b998d5a5fcac) says:

> There’s still one small problem with Parcelize though. At the moment
>   there’s an issue with Android Studio showing an error about an
>   incomplete implementation of the Parcelable interface:
>
> [image]
>
> This is a known bug in the IDE itself and you can ignore it, there’s
>   nothing wrong with the code and it works as expected. You can keep
>   track of the issue here. At the moment it’s In Progress state.

So you can just ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0):

A sample parcelable implementation would look like this:

```
data class WarriorParcelable(val name : String,
                             val weapon : String) : Parcelable {

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<WarriorParcelable> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): WarriorParcelable = WarriorParcelable(parcel)

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<WarriorParcelable?>  = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }

    private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this (parcel.readString(),parcel.readString())

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeString(name)
        dest.writeString(weapon)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0
}
```

However, if you are using the @Parcelize, you don't need to write the implementation codes for the Parcelable. It will be implemented for you.

Answer (score 0):

***@Parcelize*** is still an experimental feature, upgrade to the latest kotlin plugin version and add this code to your ***build.grade*** file

```
android {
    ...

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```

The IDE will stop complaining. As you can see below; I modified your class a bit but it's essentially this same thing.

```
@Parcelize
data class RecipeTemplate(var recipeHeader: String? = null,
                      var recipeText: String? = null,
                      var recipeImage: String? = null,
                      var recipeKey: String? = null) : Parcelable
```